# Rewriting implication als disjunction - equivalence proofs

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Given that I have to proof that the following formula is a tautology using equivalence proofs:
$$\big(∀x: P(x, C) \to (∀a: P(a, a))\big) ~\to~ ∀b : (∀c : P(c, C)) \to P(b, b)$$

I am aware that I have to rewrite this as a disjunction, but considering the formula contains four implications how do you go about rewriting it?

Is there a Youtube series/site which could help me understand equivalence proofs? I already looked around but it seems the English translation might be different.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start from the innermost one. If the formula is ambiguous, add the missing parentheses.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so always prioritise the parenthesized ones and then go left -> right?

Comment: @LLScheme Not in this case. $A→B→C$ is usually interpreted as $A→(B→C)$.  Also here it seems $\forall a: S\to T$ is meant to be read as $\forall a:(S\to T)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\big(∀x: P(x, C) \to (∀a: P(a, a))\big) ~\to~ ∀b : (∀c : P(c, C)) \to P(b, b)$$

Under the usual ordering conventions: $A\to B\to C$ is read as $A\to(B\to C)$.

**However**, usually $\to$ has precedence over quantification, but that would place $P(b,b)$ outside the scope of the universal quantifier ($\forall b$) which I am sure was not intended.  (Perhaps they are conceding precedence to the colon?)

So the implicit bracketing would appear to be

$$\Big(∀x: \color{blue}{\big(}P(x, C) \to (∀a: P(a, a))\color{blue}{\big)}\Big) ~\to~ ∀b : \color{blue}{\Big(}\big(∀c : P(c, C)\big) \to P(b, b)\color{blue}{\Big)}$$

Which is indeed a tautology.

---

So begin rewriting one step at a time. $$\Big(\forall x:\big(P(x,C)\to(\forall a: P(a,a))\big)\Big)\to\forall b:\Big(\neg\big(\forall c:P(c,C)\big)\lor P(b,b)\Big)\\~\\\Big(\forall x:\big(P(x,C)\to(\forall a: P(a,a))\big)\Big)\to\forall b:\Big(\big(\exists c:\neg P(c,C)\big)\lor P(b,b)\Big)\\~\\\neg\Big(\forall x:\big(P(x,C)\to(\forall a: P(a,a))\big)\Big)\lor\forall b:\Big(\big(\exists c:\neg P(c,C)\big)\lor P(b,b)\Big)\\~\\\vdots$$